# How to add new button and update button name in wizardpage

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, wizard

I have wizard with Finish and Cancel button.

Now I want to change Finish button name to some other. And I want to add one more new button in the same wizardpage.

Please let me know any idea.

Comment: Please take a tour [How do I ask a good question?](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

If this is a wizard being displayed by Eclipse using one of the wizard extension points then there is no way that you can access the main button bar to change it so this cannot be done.

If you create the wizard yourself using `WizardDialog` then you can override the `createButtonBar` method to change the buttons.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Is it possible with WizardPage??

Comment: No it is not possible in WizardPage. If you are not using WizardDialog to create the wizard you cannot do this.